# Error : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation Options

Tags: com, .net-4.0, autocad, dwg

I have written an external application to drive autocad with a dll that was registered for COM. I have followed [this codes](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2009/05/interfacing-an-external-com-application-with-a-net-module-in-process-to-autocad.html) to write my application however i have replaced the following code with AddNumbers() method:

```
public string OpenDWGFile(string MyDWGFilePath)
{
DocumentCollection dm = Application.DocumentManager;
Document doc = null;

if(File.Exists(MyDWGFilePath))
{
   doc = dm.Open(MyDWGFilePath, false);
   Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument = doc;
   return "This file is exists";
 }
else
   return "This file is not exist";
}
```

but when i run my application the autocad software open and then close immediatly and this error message is shown : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

but if i comment the following lines of my code the application works without any errors:

```
doc = dm.Open(MyDWGFilePath, false);
Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument = doc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a second instance of the `DocumentManager` and giving it a reference to an object retrieved from the first one. I think you want to use

```
dm.MdiActiveDocument = doc;
```